# Two variable equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm stuck with the following example (42.). Some help is much appreciated.
Thank you.
[image: problem 42.]

Comment: So if I am right you are looking for a hint to start off?

Comment: This is a modeling problem. You need to describe a mathematical model that does what you want. So you get some task described over here, and now you need to find a way to describe that task mathematically (i.e. as an equation).

Comment: Hello Predro, that's right. I have tried to solved it for about 2 h in vain.

Comment: Which equation for $x$ do we want? It is not really clear for me from the exercise. You want an equation for $x$, pretty vague.

Comment: @Pedro: The only logic thing I came up with was: x + (x-3) = 2/5(x+4)

Comment: @jhuk The question is well defined! Ask yourself what portion of the job is accomplished by each of them in one day. The sum of this will be what they accomplish together in one day. Now you can find how long the job will take for them to accomplish together from that and equate it to the value provided in the question - hence the equation. Solve for x. If it is more than 8, there will be some work for Vincent.

Comment: I really want to help here.  So, please let me know if my answer helps.  I just want to give you the best possible answer I can give you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Moti. I will follow your suggestion and try to solve it.

Comment: Let me know if you need an answer.

Comment: Hello @moti, I'm at it but haven't wrapped my head round it just yet. I understand that x = 24, but don't know how to find the days of the quicker worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "speed" problem.  The first person's speed is $v_1=1/x$ (jobs/day) and the second person's speed is $v_2=1/(x-3)$ (jobs/day).

If both work together, their collective speed is simply $v=v_1+v_2=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-3}$.  Now, at this collective speed they are able to finish $1$ job in $\frac25 (x+4)$ days.  Thus,

$$\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-3}\right)\left(\frac25 (x+4)\right)=1$$

the solutions of which are $x=1$ and $x=24$ (solutions to a quadratic equation).  But since $x>3$, then $x=24$ days.

Thus, $v_1=\frac{1}{24}$ and $v_2=\frac{1}{21}$.  If person $1$ works for $8$ days, then only $\frac13$ job is complete.  That means that person $2$ must work for $14$ days to complete this formerly incomplete job.

Comment: Dr. are you convinced about your equation?

Comment: @Moti Why do you ask?  Do you see a problem?

Comment: Because you did not create the right equation.

Comment: And why do you believe this?  What is the flaw?

Comment: My mistake. It is an accurate equation but usually written different. Hope I was not confusing.

Comment: How is it usually written?

Comment: Instead of multiplication you could use addition as you showed above: v1+v2=v